# Exclude one or more items from pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to exclude one or more items from the pandas series. For example:

```
s = pd.Series(data=range(10), index=[chr(ord('A') + x) for x in range(10)])
```

Now I want to exclude rows B, D, E

An extremely inefficient way is to do this:

```
index = s.index
for col in ['B','D','E']:
    index = index.delete(index.get_loc(col))

new_series = s[index]
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the index [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
In [11]: s.index.isin(list('BDE'))
Out[11]: array([False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

negate using the invert operator (so it now reads "not in"):

```
In [12]: ~s.index.isin(list('BDE'))
Out[12]: array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

and use this to mask the Series:

```
In [13]: s = s[~s.index.isin(list('BDE'))]

In [14]: s
Out[14]:
A    0
C    2
F    5
G    6
H    7
I    8
J    9
dtype: int64
```